# Firebase Functions Express "TypeError: handler is not a function"

Tags: javascript, firebase, express, google-cloud-functions

I have been using Firebase functions with Express according to the [Firebase docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events?gen=2nd) and I am passing my Express app as the argument for onRequest:

```
exports.myFunction = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

This works great.

To avoid cold starts and have better resonse times I want to avoid that my app scales to 0 but I can't pass the options with my app:

```
exports.myFunction = functions.https.onRequest({
    minInstances: 2,
  }, app);
```

I keep getting "TypeError: handler is not a function" in my functions logs ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/manage-functions?gen=1st#min-max-instances) for examples on how to set minInstances when using first gen functions. You use `runWith` when building the function:

```
exports.yourFunction = functions
    .runWith({
      minInstances: XX,
    })
    .https.onRequest(app);
```

Comment: Great! I was even asked "With these options, your minimum bill will be $2.31 in a 30-day month
? Would you like to proceed with deployment?"